# API to get app's description on Google Play

Tags: android, app-store, google-play

I'm trying to crawl a bunch of apps description for research purpose. Is there any available API to do this? I've got the App IDs of the apps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the lookup API for Android by 42 matters. The API is bit expensive though, But you can Find an Android app that matches the specified package name on the Google Play Store and get a full app detail.

The url is as follows - https://42matters.com/docs/app-market-data/android/apps/lookup